# Optimization problem to mimimize the function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_I)=\sum_{i=1}^I \left(\frac{x_i}{x}\right)^2$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'd like to know if there's a possible analytic way (not using computers) to minimize the following function:

$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_I)=\sum_{i=1}^I \left(\frac{x_i}{x}\right)^2$$

subject to $x=\sum_{i=1}^I x_i$, $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$.

I now it minimizes when $x_i=\frac{x}{I}$, for all $i$, but how do I prove it?

The original problem comes from the same, but every $x_i$ is an integer.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers come to mind.

Comment: Redefine $y_i=x_i/x$ such that your new cost function is $f(y_1,\dots,y_I)=\sum_{i=1}^I y_i^2$ and the constraint is now $\sum_{i=1}y_i=1$. Then use Lagrange multipliers. Can you follow from there?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: @Feedbacklooper  thanks! Solved!

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks! Solved!

Comment: Awesome, good luck!

Comment: Is $n$ the same as $I$?

Comment: @Aruralreader yes, sorry! the habit!